# Rails 4: Can't get my dynamic table generation with JQuery get working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to generate application that only produce a table when search is clicked but it seems to be not working.

What I have tried are followings.

Controller:

```
def index
@q = Link.ransack(params[:q])
@links = @q.result(distinct: true)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.js #index.js.erb
end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing Links</h1>
<!= Implements search feature using gem "Ransack" =>
<p><%= link_to 'Advanced Search', advanced_search_links_path %></p>
<%= search_form_for @q, remote: true do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name_or_address_cont %>
<%= f.search_field :name_or_address_cont %>
<%= f.submit class: 'search_submit' %>
<% end %>

<div id = 'result_table'>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ready;
var result_table = $('#result_table');

ready = function(){
  $('.search_submit').click(function(event){
    $('#result_table').replaceWith('<%= j render('table') %>');
});
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load',ready);

</script>
```

_table.html.erb:

```
<!= Implements sorting attributes using gem "Ransack" =>
<table>
<thead id= 'result_head'>
  <tr>
    <th><%= sort_link @q, :name, "Name" %></th>
    <th><%= sort_link @q, :address, "Address" %></th>
    <th>Availablity</th>
    <th>like</th>
    <th>dislike</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @links.each do |link| %>
  <tr>
    <h2>
      <td><%= link_to link.name, link %><br></td>
      <td><%= link_to link.address, link %><br></td>
      <td><%= link_to link.bedroom, link %><br></td>
      <td><%= link.get_upvotes.size %></td>
      <td><%= link.get_downvotes.size %></td>
    </h2>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<% end %>
</table>
```

The issue I am having is that whenever I click submit,

it always generates table of every data that are in Database

no matter which letter I search with.

I am also not even sure if after first table generation, when I click search for an another search, if the table is regenerated or not.

I wonder if there is something I am missing with Ajax or what.

I would really appreciate all your helps.

Please note that I am using Ransack to implement my search function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= j render('table') %>` will only get evaluated server-side, when you make a request. Please read this guide:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html